# Is itpossible to have an onscreen keyboard on the login screen

Tags: touchscreen

Is it possible to have the onscreen keyboard appear on the login screen?

Tried this in Ubuntu 16 today and it shows the onscreen keyboard on the login screen.

---

Version: Loki (64 bit)

Computer: Acer Switch Alpha 12

Comment: Can you please specify what is your question exactly?

Comment: Yes sorry that was a bit daft. I will update the post